# Getting XML data from the string

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

```
string xml = "<ABCProperties> <Action> Yes | No | None </Action><Content>
<Header> Header Text </Header><Body1> Body Paragraph 1 </Body1>
<BodyN> Body Paragraph N</BodyN></Content><IsTrue> true | false </IsTrue>
<Duration> Long | Short </Duration></ABCProperties>";
```

Here, from the XML, I want to extract certain strings.
First is the Header Text in the Header tags.

When, I try

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var a = doc.Descendants("Header").Single();
```

I get variable `a = <Header> Header Text </Header>`. How can I get only `var a =  Header Text`?

Secondly, I want to get text of all the Body paragrahs. It can be either Body1, Body2 or BodyN. How can I get contents of all Body tags.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your question doesn't make very much sense at the moment, even after I've edited the formatting a bit. A variable isn't `<Header> Header Text </Header>` - it's just a variable. If you convert the variable to a string, you might get `"<Header> Header Text </Header>` but you should clarify that that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with just getting the content node, which is what you really want, and then iterate through its children checking if it's a body or header node, and use the `string.Trim()` function to get rid of leading/trailing whitespace.:

```
string xml = @"<ABCProperties> <Action> Yes | No | None </Action><Content>
<Header> Header Text </Header><Body1> Body Paragraph 1 </Body1>
<BodyN> Body Paragraph N</BodyN></Content><IsTrue> true | false </IsTrue>
<Duration> Long | Short </Duration></ABCProperties>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

XElement content = doc.Root.Element("Content");

foreach (XElement el in content.Elements())
{
    string localName = el.Name.LocalName;

    if (localName == "Header")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(localName + ": " + el.Value.Trim());
    }
    else if (localName.StartsWith("Body"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(localName + ": " + el.Value.Trim());
    }
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: How can I do foreach loop from ABCProperties here ? Not from Content.

Comment: Just change the loop - `foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Descendants())` is probably what you want in that case

Answer (score 3):

You're asking for the `Header` *element* - so that's what it gives you. If you only want the *text* of that, you can just use:

```
var headerText = doc.Descendants("Header").Single().Value;
```

To find all the body tags, just use a `Where` clause:

```
var bodyText = doc.Descendants()
                  .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("Body"))
                  .Select(x => x.Value);
```